# MySQL next row ORDER BY multiple columns JOIN table 2

Tags: mysql

I need help limiting the results set of this query.

```
SELECT tt.id
FROM kf_topics AS tt
LEFT JOIN kf_posts AS pp
ON tt.id = pp.topicid
WHERE tt.boardid = 1
GROUP BY tt.id
ORDER BY tt.sticky DESC, pp.time DESC
```

Current returns the array below.

[image]

However, I need to find the row in the list AFTER the row with the ID that I specify, bearing in mind these will change order ALOT based on the ORDER BY tt.sticky DESC, pp.time DESC. Also, the rows will never be in perfect ID order, so basing it on the ID field is out of the question.

So for example, if I wanted to find the next row after ID = 24, the query result would be ID => 23

Answer (score 3):

We can do that using a single query as follows

```
SELECT ttid
FROM 
(SELECT tt.id ttid,@row:=@row+1 rownum,IF(tt.id=24,@j:=@row,0)
FROM kf_topics AS tt
LEFT JOIN kf_posts AS pp
ON tt.id = pp.topicid JOIN (SELECT @row:=0) AS rowcount
WHERE tt.boardid = 1
GROUP BY tt.id
ORDER BY tt.sticky DESC, pp.time DESC) A JOIN (SELECT @j+1 as rownum) B ON (A.rownum=B.rownum);
```

I am not sure why you are using group by,but it should work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @row:=0;
SELECT rownum+1 INTO @nextrow FROM 
   (SELECT tt.id AS id, @row AS rownum
   FROM kf_topics AS tt
   LEFT JOIN kf_posts AS pp
   ON tt.id = pp.topicid
   WHERE tt.boardid = 1
   AND (@row:=@row+1)<=1
   GROUP BY tt.id
   ORDER BY tt.sticky DESC, pp.time DESC) A
WHERE A.id=<id>)
SET @row=0;
SELECT A.id FROM 
  (SELECT tt.id AS id, @row AS rownum
   FROM kf_topics AS tt
   LEFT JOIN kf_posts AS pp
   ON tt.id = pp.topicid
   WHERE tt.boardid = 1
   AND (@row:=@row+1)<=1
   GROUP BY tt.id
   ORDER BY tt.sticky DESC, pp.time DESC) A 
WHERE A.rownum=@nextrow
```

This can be rewritten into single query. The above query is not optimized, but will give the result you need. I will think again and try to post the opmized query.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think the query you provided is getting the next row in the unsorted list, not once the list has been sorted?